# Win32 Listview disable item label edit

Tags: c++, winapi

I have win32 listview that I subclassed to allow column edit.
I want to allow editing of some columns and disable for the rest. The actual edit happens on LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT. In case column is not editable I return FALSE from handler and edit is canceled. The problem is that at this stage the editbox already visible. Is there a way to block this altogether so it will look like listview is not editable?

```
LRESULT  TabbedUI::OnListViewClick(
    int /* idCtrl */,
    LPNMHDR  pNMHDR,
    BOOL & bHandled)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pia = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
    if (pia->iItem != -1 && pia->iSubItem != -1) {
        itemId_ = pia->iItem;
        subItemId_ = pia->iSubItem;
    }
    bHandled = FALSE;
    return 1;
}

LRESULT TabbedUI::OnBeginLabelEdit(
    int idCtrl,
    LPNMHDR pNMHDR,
    BOOL& bHandled)
{
    auto& info = *reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    ATLASSERT(info.hdr.hwndFrom == listView_.m_hWnd); // Make sure subclassed listview is the one

    if (IsReadOnlyColumn(subItemId_))
    {
        listView_.SendMessage(LVM_CANCELEDITLABEL, 0, 0);
        listView_.SendMessage(WM_CANCELMODE, 0, 0);
        ::SendMessage(ListView_GetEditControl(listView_.m_hWnd), WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
        bHandled = TRUE;
        return 1;
    }

    if (subItemId_ > 0) // verify if subitem editing
    {
        inEdit_ = true; // set flag to true

        // Get rect of item and block its update
        RECT rc = {};
        ListView_GetItemRect(listView_.m_hWnd, itemId_, &rc, LVIR_LABEL);
        listView_.ValidateRect(&rc);

        // Get edit control
        listViewEdit_.SubclassWindow(ListView_GetEditControl(listView_.m_hWnd));

        // get RECT of subitem being edited
        ListView_GetSubItemRect(listView_.m_hWnd, itemId_, subItemId_, LVIR_LABEL, &rc);

        // get text of edited subitem
        ListView_GetItemText(listView_.m_hWnd, itemId_, subItemId_, szText_, 256);

        rcSubItem_ = rc;

        // get column width and save it on rcSubItem.right to resize edit ctrl
        rcSubItem_.right = ListView_GetColumnWidth(listView_.m_hWnd, subItemId_);

        // set edit text 
        listViewEdit_.SetWindowText(szText_);
    }

    // Finally return FALSE to allow item editing
    bHandled = FALSE;
    return 0;
}

LRESULT TabbedUI::OnEndLabelEdit(
    int idCtrl,
    LPNMHDR  pNMHDR,
    BOOL& bHandled)
{
    // End Label editing
    auto& info = *reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    ATLASSERT(info.hdr.hwndFrom == listView_.m_hWnd); // Make sure subclassed listview is the one

    auto& item = info.item;

    if (subItemId_)  // Is subitem ?
    {
        if (item.pszText != NULL) // Is text == NULL
        {
            wstring s(item.pszText);
            size_t dwLen = s.size(); // strlen of inserted text
            if (dwLen > 0) // has some text ?
                ListView_SetItemText(listView_.m_hWnd, itemId_, subItemId_, item.pszText);
        }
        // unsubclass edit
        listViewEdit_.UnsubclassWindow();

        subItemId_ = 0; // reset values
        inEdit_ = false;

        SaveActiveTabEditedItems();
    }
    bHandled = FALSE;
    return 0;
}

LRESULT TabbedUI::OnListViewEditWindowPosChanging(
    UINT,
    WPARAM /* wParam */,
    LPARAM lParam,
    BOOL& bHandled)
{
    WINDOWPOS *pos = reinterpret_cast<WINDOWPOS*>(lParam);
    pos->x = rcSubItem_.left;
    pos->cx = rcSubItem_.right;
    bHandled = TRUE;
    return 0;
}

LRESULT TabbedUI::OnTabSelectionChange(
    int /* idCtrl */,
    LPNMHDR /* pNMHDR */,
    BOOL& bHandled)
{
    Tab* pTab = GetSelectedTab();

    if (listView_.m_hWnd)
        listView_.UnsubclassWindow();
    listView_.SubclassWindow(pTab->hListView);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT TabbedUI::OnListViewPaint(
    UINT /*uMsg*/,
    WPARAM /*wParam*/,
    LPARAM /*lParam*/,
    BOOL& bHandled)
{

    bHandled = FALSE;

    BOOL ok = FALSE;
    if (!inEdit_)
        return 0;

    if (subItemId_ > 0) {
        RECT rcItem = {};
        ok = ListView_GetItemRect(listView_.m_hWnd, itemId_, &rcItem, LVIR_LABEL);
        if (ok) listView_.ValidateRect(&rcItem);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-beginlabeledit): "*To allow the user to edit the label, return FALSE. To prevent the user from editing the label, return TRUE.*"  You have your `return` value backwards.  If needed, have you tried sending `LVM_CANCELEDITLABEL`or `WM_CANCELMODE` to the ListView? Worst case, you could just try `Destroy\Window()` on the edit window returned by `LVM_GETEDITCONTROL` (even though the docs say not to).

Comment: I tried your idea but it did not help. It looks like OnBeginLabelEdit is called after the edit box already appeared.

Comment: not according to the documentation: “*When label editing begins, an edit control is created, positioned, and initialized. **Before it is displayed**, the list-view control sends its parent window an LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT notification code.*”

Comment: I posted the relevant code. Edit box still showing up on single mouse click.  Maybe it is not editbox itself but some indication that item label is expected to be edited.

Comment: Is this `winapi` or maybe `mfc`? winapi (Win32) is not C++. And read carefully "To allow the user to edit the label, return FALSE." - you have to return TRUE to disable editing.

Comment: `::SendMessage(ListView_GetEditControl(listView_.m_hWnd), WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);` - sending a `WM_DESYROY` message does not destroy a window. You would have to call `DestroyWindow()` instead. Which the ListView will do for you when editing is canceled.

Comment: The project uses ATL . Not MFC .

Comment: I return 0; Should be the same as false.  I mean this part works. I can edit both editable and non editable columns. But this return 1 or 0 causes my edits to non editable columns to be discarded. So the behavior is correct.  The only issue is that edit box or just frame showing up for read only columns.

Comment: In other words, you can already disable item label editing, but the non editable columns will be deleted. You don’t want them to be deleted, but keep them read-only, right? If this is what I said, it will be a new problem. Maybe you can post a new thread to seek answers.

Comment: Non editable columns are not deleted. They behave the same way as editable ones. When focus leaves the non editable column old value is restored. For editable columns the values becomes new value. I want to block edits to begin with.